# ksqlDB deleting records from KTable

Tags: ksqldb, ktable

• We have a topic “customer_events“ in Kafka. Example of value.

```
{ 
  "CUSTOMERID": "198fa518-1031-4fe8-8abd-ca29bd120259"
}
```

• We created a persistent stream over the topic in ksqlDB cluster in Confluent.

```
CREATE STREAM TEST_STREAM 
(SESSIONID STRING KEY, CUSTOMERID STRING) WITH 
(KAFKA_TOPIC='customer_events', KEY_FORMAT='KAFKA', PARTITIONS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

• We created derived table over the stream in ksqlDB cluster in Confluent. The table aggregates customers according to SessionId.

```
CREATE TABLE QUERYABLE_TESTTABLE AS SELECT
   SRC.SESSIONID SESSIONID,
   COLLECT_LIST(SRC.CUSTOMERID) CUSTOMERS
FROM TEST_STREAM SRC
GROUP BY SRC.SESSIONID
EMIT CHANGES;
```

• We then query the table (pull query):

```
SELECT * from  QUERYABLE_TESTTABLE ;
```

• The whole flow works fine (INSERT and UPDATE). The results are like expected.

| SessionId | customers |
| --- | --- |
| "3e45e7ac-781b-4213-b288-b3f95836487c" | [ "198fa518-1031-4fe8-8abd-ca29bd120259", "bb1494de-bc1a-429b-a2b0-68684ed01d17"] |
| "88db0272-db35-48e9-b7ec-b326a9cde106" | [ "bc4ab46c-5e79-4ca6-af67-74688105a5c0"] |
| ... | ... |

**But how to remove the items from the QUERYABLE_TESTTABLE table?**

We tried to insert tombstone into customer_events topic. We tried to insert tombstone into underlying topic of the QUERYABLE_TESTTABLE table, which I know is not the best idea. We search the internet, there is no clear description how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using STREAM which doesn't read tombstone (value as null) event in the 1st place. Solution is more of a re-design. I can't think of any other solution to this problem.

If you have control over what you are publishing, instead of publishing tombstone event to customer_events table.

- Add a new column. Column can be called `__deleted`.
- By default populate `false` if you want to delete the key just make it `true`.
- Add a simple where clause in your derived table `WHERE __deleted != 'true'`.
- To also have tombstone at final table as well. Or else you will see empty array if all records for a given SESSIONID is deleted.
  Just add a having clause at the end to check array size greater than 0 to create a tombstone even.
  `ARRAY_LENGTH(COLLECT_LIST(SRC.CUSTOMERID)) > 0`

*Note: You can easily do this even if your source connector is debezium. It provides out of the box class to do it*